# How clear the back stack activities on press of back Key in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an android application where there are 3 activities:

MA – MainActivity (Launched when the application is started)
AC1 – Activity1 – declared as androidLaunchMode=”singleInstance”
AC2- Activity2- declared as androidLaunchMode=”singleInstance”

Initial flow of activities is 
MA -> AC1 
Go back to MA
MA -> AC2

So the total flow is like MA -> AC1 -> MA -> AC2
Now when I press back I want the flow to be
AC2  -> MA to close application.

So, on back press of MA I want to clear the back stack of activities.
So, how to I handle this in onKeyDown() of MA?

Comment: I think you have to finish activity on back press.

Comment: I tried finishing. But nothing happens. Even onDestroy() is not called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are calling MA from AC1 put below flag as intent

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
```

and

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

Comment: I tried calling these flags from AC2->MA. That is the requirement. But did not work. Still I can see the older activities in the stack. Is there any easy way to clear all the activities in a stack without showing to the user?

Comment: You havent read the answer carefully I said the time you call MA from AC1 then set both flags it will work

Comment: Thanks Saurabh. Still the issue persists. My problem is launching of activities goes on well. But when I press back key then all the visited activities remain in the stack. I dont want that.

Comment: Are you calling finish on AC1 when you call MA

Comment: No I am not calling... I should not call as per the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

What about setting [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) flag?

Answer (score 0):

Try startActivityForResult()

Go through the following links

http://micropilot.tistory.com/1577
http://rahulonblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-startactivityforresult-example.html